# How to draw a dashed line using Matplotlib's ConnectionPatch?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I change the linestyle of the line drawn by the ConnectionPatch? It would be best if the usual linestyles ":", "--", or "-" would work. The ConnectionPatch code I was using is:

```
con = ConnectionPatch(color=seas_col[iseas],linewidth=2,
   xyA=(mean_vals_1[isn,iseas],0), 
   xyB=(mean_vals_2[isn,iseas],3000), 
   coordsA="data", coordsB="data",
   axesA=axarr[0], axesB=axarr[1])
```

Both the arrowstyle and connectionstyle don't accept the above mentioned styles.

[image: Example Fig, the connection lines should match the above linestyles.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is not to use the short hand notation, but the long forms, e.g. "dotted","dashed","solid" which work for the linestyle keyword.